# Шифрование keccak256 короткая версия

Tags: javascript

Есть ли сокращенные до одного файла библиотеки шифрования keccak256? Просто что не смотрю все библиотеки в несколько файлов, и с набором 512, 384 и т.п.

Comment: ну, вот [тут](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha3), например, все в одном файле. Ненужные алгоритмы можно элементарно закомментировать.

Comment: @Yaant У меня боль в том, что по ряду причин это засовывается в эмулятор js кода. А он принимает только конструкции из разряда function kec() {}

Comment: @Yaant по этому и ищу где именно онли есть keccak256, а мои попытки закомментировать данную библиотеку от лишнего были обречены на провал.